# Can you skip these thread calls in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, multithreading, breakpoints

When I run my app and set breakpoints to step through, I eventually get here. What does this mean and can I skip these stops on thread code like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode will allow you to step through your own code.  Of you "step over" or "step out" your instruction pointer will eventually end up pointing somewhere that is no longer your source code, like a dynamic framework.  What you will see there is the assembly code (actual machine instructions), which is useful if you learn how to read it.  [Here is a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/37181/ios-assembly-tutorial) that will help you start to understand it.

If you just want to get your instruction pointer back to your own source code, a "step out" might get you there.  Usually, you just have to put another breakpoint in your code which you expect to run next.

Answer (score 0):

That's mean your application is crashing some where. add `Exceptional breakpoints` to check where your application is crashing. And remove other break points if you have set.

Comment: Actually, this does not look like a crash.  It looks like the instruction pointer just wandered into a dispatch block that is not part of the source code.